# Using Eigen in MATLAB MEX

Tags: matlab, eigen, mex

I have encountered an issue when using Eigen in MATLAB MEX files.

Consider this excerpt of code, in which I call a mex function to create an object of the class `vars`.  The class has an integer `N`, an integer `S`, and two `Eigen` arrays.

```
//constructMat.cpp

class vars {

public:
    int N
    int S
    Eigen::ArrayXd upperLims
    Eigen::ArrayXd lowerLims

stateVars (double *, double *, double *)

};

stateVars::stateVars (double *upperInput, double *lowerInput, double *gridInput)

    Eigen::ArrayXd upper; upper = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(upperInput, sizeof(*upperInput),1);
    Eigen::ArrayXd lower; lower = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(lowerInput, sizeof(*lowerInput),1);
    Eigen::ArrayXd gridSizes; gridSizes = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(gridInput, sizeof(*gridInput),1);
    upperLims = upper;
    lowerLims = lower;
    N = upperLims.size();
    S = gridSizes.prod();
}

//MEX CODE
void
mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    //....checks to make sure the inputs are okay...

    double* upper = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double* lower = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    double* grids = mxGetPr(prhs[2]);

    stateVars stateSpace(upper, lower, grids);

    mexPrintf("N =%f  \n\n", stateSpace.N  );
    mexPrintf("S =%f  \n\n", stateSpace.S  );
}
```

However, when I execute the function, I call `constructMat([7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [4.0, 2.0, 3.0], [10, 10, 10])`, and I expect `mexPrintf("N =%f  \n\n", stateSpace.N  )` to yield `3` since the array `upperLims` only has three elements. However, it yields `7`. Similarly, I expect `mexPrintf("S =%f  \n\n", stateSpace.S  )` to yield 10^3 = 1000, but it yields 7 as well. I'm not sure what I did wrong. The mex file was compiled successfully.

Also, if I call `mexPrintf("upperlims =%f  \n\n",stateSpace.upperLims(0) )`, i.e. printing out the first element of the `Eigen` array `upperLims`, it gives me the right number. Does it have something to do with the method `.size()` and `.prod()`?